# Loop through each value in a table and supply that value as a parameter to a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I need to loop through each value in `#TempTable` and use that value as a parameter for `MyFunction`

Function `MyFunction` simply returns another column based on  `ID_col` in `#TempTable`

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTable
select 'ID1' as ID_col
into #TempTable
union select all 'ID2'
union select all 'ID3'

DECLARE @PriorID_col varchar(50)
DECLARE @ReturnVal varchar(50) = ''

SELECT TOP 1 PriorID_col = #TempTable.ID_col

-- here I need to loop through each ID_col in #TempTable and supply it as a parameter to "MyFunction"
WHILE MyFunction(#TempTable.ID_col) IS NOT NULL 
 BEGIN
        SET @PriorID_col = MyFunction(@PriorID_col)
    END
-- querying ID from real table based on variable @PriorID_col
SELECT TOP 1 @ReturnVal = ID
FROM         MyTable
WHERE        MyTable.ID = @PriorID_col
```

But I am unable to loop through each value in a `#TempTable`.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The best thing you could do is re-write `MyFunction()` or add an additional function to let you work with a full set. This will gain you at least an order of magnitude performance improvement... probably two.

Comment: Thanks Joel. The logic wasn't describe well in this question. This is what I really need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727052/how-to-loop-through-table-using-while-loop-and-create-another-table-with-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your logic quite works, and your `union all` certainly doesn't. You are getting a value for each row in the temp table, but only using one of those values to obtain the return value, and there doesn't appear to be any relationship between them.

Anyway I have shown the basic premise for iterating through the rows in a temp table. Essentially...

1. Get the top row
2. Do something with it
3. Delete it

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTable;

SELECT 'ID1' AS ID_col
INTO #TempTable
UNION ALL SELECT 'ID2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ID3';

DECLARE @ID_col VARCHAR(50), @PriorID_col VARCHAR(50), @ReturnVal VARCHAR(50) = '';

-- here I need to loop through each ID_col in #TempTable and supply it as a parameter to "MyFunction"
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempTable.ID_col)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @ID_col = ID_col #TempTable.ID_col;
    SET @PriorID_col = dbo.MyFunction(@ID_col)
    DELETE FROM #TempTable.ID_col WHERE ID_col = @ID_col
END;

-- querying ID from real table based on variable @PriorID_col
SELECT TOP 1 @ReturnVal = ID
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.ID = @PriorID_col;
```

Comment: Thanks Dale. I am looking into it. Meanwhile I posted a function that is exists and works. Maybe this will help to understand what Im trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, wouldn't simple `SELECT` ... `WHERE` work for this scenario.

```
SELECT 'ID1' AS ID_col
INTO #TempTable
UNION ALL SELECT 'ID2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ID3';

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.Id IN (SELECT MyFunction(@ID_col) FROM #TempTable)
```

Comment: Hey Fabio, sorry the logic wasnt described well in this question. This is what I really need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727052/how-to-loop-through-table-using-while-loop-and-create-another-table-with-values