# How to loop through table using while loop and create another table with values needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, recursive-query

I have two tables: `MainTable` and `MyTable`. MyTable has unique ControlNo and ID. I need to add very first `EffDate`  from `MainTable` to `MyTable`based on `ID` and `ControlNo`.

[image]

For that I need to look at `PreviousID` column, then see if that `PreviousID` is in `ID` column and so on.

[image]

**Desired output should look like this:**

[image]

---

The below is an example with dummy data of getting proper `EffDate` by supplying an `ID` value. It works, but how can I loop through the whole `MainTable`, retrieve `ID`'s and `EffDate` into separate table, then join that table to `MyTable`?

```
-- function returns PreviousID based on ID
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPriorQuoteID](@ID varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetVal varchar(50)
    SET @RetVal = NULL
    
    SELECT TOP 1 @RetVal = MainTable.PreviousID
    FROM         MainTable
    WHERE        MainTable.ID = @ID
    
    RETURN @RetVal
END

    -- create sample table
    IF OBJECT_ID('MainTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE MainTable;
    select 3333 as ControlNo, 'QuoteID3' as ID, 'QuoteID2' as PreviousID, '2020-08-25' as EffDate 
    into MainTable
    union all select 2222 as COntrolNo, 'QuoteID2', 'QuoteID1', '2019-08-25'
    union all select 1111 as COntrolNo, 'QuoteID1', NULL, '2018-08-25'
    union all select 7777 as COntrolNo, 'QuoteID6', 'QuoteID5', '2020-02-10'
    union all select 6666 as COntrolNo, 'QuoteID5', NULL, '2019-02-10'
    select * from MainTable
    
    
    DECLARE @PriorQuote varchar(50)
    DECLARE @RetVal VARCHAR(50) = ''
    DECLARE @ControlNo INT
    DECLARE @ID varchar(50) = 'QuoteID3'
    
    SELECT TOP 1 @ControlNo = MainTable.ControlNo FROM MainTable WHERE MainTable.ID = @ID
    Set @PriorQuote = @ID
    
    SELECT TOP 1 @PriorQuote = MainTable.ID FROM MainTable WHERE MainTable.ControlNo = @ControlNo 
    
    WHILE dbo.GetPriorQuoteID(@PriorQuote) IS NOT NULL AND dbo.GetPriorQuoteID(@PriorQuote)<> @PriorQuote
    BEGIN
            SET @PriorQuote = dbo.GetPriorQuoteID(@PriorQuote)
        END
    
    
    SELECT TOP 1 @RetVal = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MainTable.EffDate, 101)
    FROM         MainTable
    WHERE        MainTable.ID = @PriorQuote
    SELECT @RetVal
    
    -- clean up
    drop table MainTable
    drop function GetPriorQuoteID
```

UPDATE: Adding dummy data tables

```
-- create sample table #MainTable
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MainTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MainTable;
create table #MainTable (ControlNo int, ID varchar(50), PreviousID varchar(50), EffDate date)
insert into #MainTable values
(3333,'QuoteID3','QuoteID2', '2020-08-25'),
(2222,'QuoteID2','QuoteID1', '2019-08-25'),
(1111,'QuoteID1',NULL, '2018-08-25'),
(7777,'QuoteID6','QuoteID5', '2020-02-10'),
(6666,'QuoteID5',NULL, '2019-02-10')
--select * from #MainTable

-- create sample table #MyTable
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTable;
create table #MyTable (ControlNo int, ID varchar(50), EffDate date)
insert into #MyTable values 
(3333,'QuoteID3',NULL),
(7777,'QuoteID6',NULL)
--select * from #MyTable
```

Comment: "Why do you want to loop in the first place?" : Probably since he is coming from the developing world and seen help to understand that Tabular databases works best with SET of rows and not row by row :-)

Comment: Oh, if there is a way I can avoid loop that would be awesome.

Comment: I thought about using joins but but ithe number of PreviousID's is not constant

Comment: Separate side note, you are better off with a inline table-value function over that scalar function. It also has a `TOP 1`, but no `ORDER BY`, meaning that *any* arbitrary row can be returned, and that could easily not be the same one everytime you run said function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive query to traverse the hierarchy.

I would start by joining the original table with the main table, which restricts the paths to just the rows we are interested in. Then, you can recurse towards the parent. Finally, we need to filter on the top parent per path: `top()` and `row_number()` come handy for this.

Consider:

```
with cte as (
    select t.controlno, t.id, m.previousid, m.effdate, 1 lvl 
    from #maintable m
    inner join #mytable t on t.controlno = m.controlno and t.id = m.id
    union all
    select c.controlno, c.id, m.previousid, m.effdate, c.lvl + 1
    from cte c
    inner join #maintable m on m.id = c.previousid
)
select top(1) with ties controlno, id, effdate
from cte 
order by row_number() over(partition by controlno, id order by lvl desc)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4895bc43d90ba4cecb0f6565ba5bc03f)**:

```
controlno | id       | effdate   
--------: | :------- | :---------
     3333 | QuoteID3 | 2018-08-25
     7777 | QuoteID6 | 2019-02-10
```

Comment: This is not a good solution in first glance. There is no reason to do the JOIN which cost a lot in each iteration  of the recursive.

Comment: @RonenAriely: not at all. As I explained in my answer, the join happens in the anchor of the query only, which limits the number of rows that we then need to iterate on to those that we really need.

Answer (score 2):

using CTE like below you can get the desired results.
<kbd>[See live demo](https://rextester.com/CNWB41500)</kbd>

Learn more about recursive CTEs [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/)

```
 ; with cte as 
   (
       select EffDate, ControlNo, ID, Level=1 from MainTable
       where PreviousID is NULL
       union all
       select C.EffDate, M.ControlNo, M.ID, Level=Level+1 from MainTable AS M
       join cte as C on C.ID=M.PreviousID
     )
     
    select MyTable.*,cte.EffDate from cte join MyTable on Mytable.ID=cte.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
WITH cte 
AS
(

SELECT m.ID,m.PreviousID
FROM MainTable m
JOIN MainTable m2
     ON m.previousID = m2.ID
WHERE m2.previousID IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT m2.ID,cte.previousID
FROM cte
JOIN MainTable m2
     ON m2.previousID = cte.ID

)

SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of the CTE approach with the table provided

```
;with recur_cte(ControlNo, ID, PreviousID, EffDate, HLevel) as (
    select mt.ControlNo, cast(null as varchar(100)), mt.PreviousID, mt.EffDate, 1
    from MainTable mt
    where not exists(select 1 
                     from MainTable mt_in
                     where mt.ID=mt_in.PreviousID)
    union all
    select rc.ControlNo, rc.ID, mt.PreviousID, mt.EffDate, rc.HLevel+1
    from recur_cte rc
         join MainTable mt on rc.PreviousID=mt.ID and rc.EffDate>mt.EffDate)
select * from recur_cte;
```

Results

```
ControlNo   ID  PreviousID  EffDate HLevel
3333    NULL    QuoteID2    2020-08-25  1
7777    NULL    QuoteID5    2020-02-10  1
7777    NULL    NULL        2019-02-10  2
3333    NULL    QuoteID1    2019-08-25  2
3333    NULL    NULL        2018-08-25  3
```